# insert a query to database table to prevent auto increment to skip numbers

Tags: php, mysql, database

If user registration has failed, ID (which is set to `AUTO INCREMENT`) skips a number. To prevent this, I came up with the code below. But rather inserting the word '**Registration error**' to `winningSegment` under table `tb_prizewon` it only prints the message in die() function

```
if (!$success) {
    $query2   = "INSERT into tb_prizewon (winningSegment) VALUES('Registration error')";
    die("Number already registered! Please try again.");
}
```

winningSegment is supposed to be the `prize` won by the user after spinning a `wheel of fortune` after a successful registration of his info. `tb_prizewon` table also have an AUTO_INCREMENT field for ID

Comment: That code **does not execute** any SQL. It assigns a string to a variable and then .. dies.

Comment: How are we supposed to know what `winningSegment` is? Can you please give more details and then we will try yo help you

Comment: If registration is failed and __no record inserted__ then there's no skipped number.

Comment: Lolx! @user2864740 has got it correct & ought to post that as the answer.

Comment: Same for @u_mulder - this is probably the correct answer, ***BUT*** only if we can see what the SQL prior to the code snippet is trying to do

Comment: @Mawg winningSegment is supposed to be the `prize` won by the user after spinning a `wheel of fortune` after a successful registration of his info

Comment: You have an SQL injection vulnerability.

Answer (score 0):

You are not executing the query which you have formatted.

Also, make sure that `tb_prizewon` table have AUTO_INCREMENT field for ID and it could be better if you enclose the fieldname winningSegment with backstick as `winningSegment`

Answer (score 0):

You have to be set **default value**  for other fields in your table, unless you define another field in your query. For example if you have 4 field in **tb_prizewon** you must have Something like this

```
$query2   = "INSERT into tb_prizewon (winningSegment,name,username,password) VALUES('Registration error','1\','','')";
```

Comment: Finally somebody understood what I'm trying to explain! Thank you it is working now